# Magento 2.2: Want to add a category tree like structure field in admin custom module

Tags: module, magento2.2, admin-panel, category-tree, custom-field

I have created 2 custom admin module, I want to add a category like tree structure in my module 2, that will take values from module 1.

Or can create multiselect for show as below senario:

```
┳ RootName
├─┬ SubRoot1
│ ├── Child1
│ ├── Child2
│ └── Child3
└─┬ SubRoot2
  ├── Child1
  └── Child2
```

My form is created via Ui Component.